# How to get the file name of a file in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I make a search program for searching a list of files in a computer and then copy the file into a store folder. The file name could be "*11*2.txt" As long as the program find this pattern, it should copy to the store folder. The problem is that I don't know the exactly name of the file before the search and I don't want to rename the file, I don't know how to save the file. Please help

I use the following to find the file, which does its work

```
Public Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String, ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim To_Path As String
    To_Path = Form1.TextBox5.Text
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(sDir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, FileName)
        Copy2Local(foundFile, To_Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the current version  of the Copy2Local (Note: it is not working right)

```
    Public Sub Copy2Local(ByVal Copy_From_Path As String, ByVal Copy_To_Path As String)
    ' Specify the directories you want to manipulate.

    Try
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Copy_From_Path)
        fs.Close()


        ' Copy the file.
        File.Copy(Copy_From_Path, Copy_To_Path)
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks for your suggestion. VB says it cannot find the Copy_To_Path. I set Copy_To_Path as a folder name, which is wrong. It should be a file name. However, I don't know how I should set it as a file name if I do a search of "*ab*c.txt" (Note: I want to keep what the program search. In other word, if the result is ab1c.txt, I want to copy this file into the store folder with renaming). Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you should check if `ToPath` is a valid directory since it's coming from a `TextBox`:

```
Dim isValidDir = Directory.Exists(ToPath)
```

Second, you can use `Path.Combine` to create a path from separate (sub)directories or file-names:

```
Dim copyToDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Copy_To_Path)
Dim file = Path.GetFileName(Copy_From_Path)
Dim newPath = Path.Combine(copyToDir, file)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

<sub>(disclaimer: typed from a mobile)</sub>

Comment: I give you an A plus. Clear and simple

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You can get the file name with [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx). Example:

```
Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(foundFile)
```

---

However, there's a bunch of other things wrong with your code:

1. Here,

   ```
   Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Copy_From_Path)
   fs.Close()
   ```

   you are [*overwriting* your source file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx). This does not seem like a good idea. ;-)
2. And here,

   ```
   Try
       ...
   Catch
       ' Do Nothing
   End Try
   ```

   You are throwing away exceptions that would help you find and diagnose problems. Don't do that. It makes debugging a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, I'm using the following code to find the filename

```
Textbox1.Text = New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName).Name
```

this code work fine with open file dialog box